# Change list in python

Tags: python, list, python-itertools

How can make several lists like this:

```
['The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring (2001)']

['The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers (2002)']

['"5 Second Movies" (2007) {The Lord of the Rings and the Two Towers (#1.63)}']
```

Into one list like this:

```
 ['The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring (2001)',
'The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers (2002)',
'"5 Second Movies" (2007) {The Lord of the Rings and the Two Towers (#1.63)}']
```

I have tried this:

```
x = open("ratings.list.txt","r")
movread = x.readlines()
x.close()



#s = raw_input('Search: ').lower()
for ns in movread:


    if 'the lord of the' in ns.lower():
        d = re.split('\s+',ns,4)
        Title = d[4].rstrip()
        Rating= d[3]



        lists = [Title]

        combined = [item for sublist in lists for item in sublist]
        print combined
```

But its gives me this output:

```
['T', 'h', 'e', ' ', 'L', 'o', 'r', 'd', ' ', 'o', 'f', ' ', 't', 'h', 'e', ' ', 'R', 'i', 'n', 'g', 's', ':', ' ', 'T', 'h', 'e', ' ', 'R', 'e', 't', 'u', 'r', 'n', ' ', 'o', 'f', ' ', 't', 'h', 'e', ' ', 'K', 'i', 'n', 'g', ' ', '(', '2', '0', '0', '3', ')']
['T', 'h', 'e', ' ', 'L', 'o', 'r', 'd', ' ', 'o', 'f', ' ', 't', 'h', 'e', ' ', 'R', 'i', 'n', 'g', 's', ':', ' ', 'T', 'h', 'e', ' ', 'F', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 'w', 's', 'h', 'i', 'p', ' ', 'o', 'f', ' ', 't', 'h', 'e', ' ', 'R', 'i', 'n', 'g', ' ', '(', '2', '0', '0', '1', ')']
```

Thanks for the help guys :D

UPDATE

The file look like this (its a list of all the movies on IMDB, so the size is huge):

```
New  Distribution  Votes  Rank  Title
      0000000125  1196672   9.2  The Shawshank Redemption (1994)
      0000000125  829707   9.2  The Godfather (1972)
      0000000124  547511   9.0  The Godfather: Part II (1974)
      0000000124  1160800   8.9  The Dark Knight (2008)
      0000000124  920221   8.9  Pulp Fiction (1994)
      0000000124  358790   8.9  Il buono, il brutto, il cattivo. (1966)
      0000000123  605734   8.9  Schindler's List (1993)
      0000000133  297241   8.9  12 Angry Men (1957)
      0000000124  854409   8.9  The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King (2003)
      0000000123  910109   8.8  Fight Club (1999)
      0000000124  880827   8.8  The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring (2001)
      0000000123  568723   8.8  Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back (1980)
      0000000124  953140   8.7  Inception (2010)
```

Comment: How about just `[sub[0] for sub in original]`?

Comment: I suggest you to read the file in and split via newlines instead of character by character.

Comment: How do i do that? im not good at python just started with it ! @Stupid.Fat.Cat

Answer (score 0):

You want to

```
[movie[0] for movie in movies]
```

An example script would look like this

```
import pprint    

movies = [
['The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring (2001)'],
['The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers (2002)'],
['"5 Second Movies" (2007) {The Lord of the Rings and the Two Towers (#1.63)}'],
]

pprint.pprint([movie[0] for movie in movies], indent=4)
```

This outputs

```
[   'The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring (2001)',
    'The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers (2002)',
    '"5 Second Movies" (2007) {The Lord of the Rings and the Two Towers (#1.63)}']
```

The `movies` list, would be populated by you when you read in the file.

Comment: my problem is that its a huge file withe more lists than the three i showed you !

Comment: the lists is not seperated by comma

Comment: Read your file by line, adding each line to the movies list. Then they will be separated by commas

Answer (score 0):

Reading them as lines from a text file, you could do the following:

It looks like you want to be able to search for titles, so in that case:

```
search = raw_input("Enter title: ").lower()

with open("ratings.list.txt") as f:
    titles = [line for line in f if search in line.lower()]
```

That code would return you the *whole* line. What you do with the line is up to you.

For instance, to extract the *title+year* from the line, you could do:

```
for title in titles:
    print title.strip().split(' ', 6)
```

example:

If line was:

```
     0000000125  1196672   9.2  The Shawshank Redemption (1994)
```

output would be:

```
['0000000125', '', '1196672', '', '', '9.2', ' The Shawshank Redemption (1994)']
```

Comment: my problem is that its a huge file withe more lists than the three i showed you !

Comment: So is there more than just movie titles in this file?

Comment: If this file only contains movie titles, one on each line, then the code above for opening the text file should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your actual problem is much more involved that just the question of appending lists. You might consider a database for the results.

But regarding your original question:

If you are just trying to collapse the list of lists into a list of strings, there is a nice trick, to use `sum`:

```
>>> listoflists = [['abc'],['def'],['g'],['abc'],['abcdefg']]
>>> sum(listoflists,[])
['abc', 'def', 'g', 'abc', 'abcdefg']
```

You could also use list comprehension, which was actually faster in my test:

```
combined = [ x[0] for x in listoflists ]
```

But the fastest way, if the items are list elements, would be to add them to `combined` as you create it instead of requiring a separate loop at the end:

```
#Outside the loop
combined = []

# inside the loop
title = d[4].rstrip()
lists = [title]
combined += lists
```

There seems to be no reason to make that intermediate `Lists` variable, though, and instead just use:

```
title = d[4].rstrip()
combined.append(title)
```

You probably want to move your `print combined` outside the loop so it just prints it in the end.